# Estimate base-spreading resistance from Gummel-Poon model

Tags: bjt, noise, spice

I'm attempting to calculate the base-spreading resistance of BJTs from manufacturer-provided SPICE models, which use the Gummel-Poon model. [This Agilent publication](https://drive.google.com/file/d/191orFYjncfSK-a2Ztl2d2AtSnDbEgU6a/view?usp=sharing) ([Internet Archive link here, if needed](http://web.archive.org/web/20220209193638/http://www.idea2ic.com/PlayWithSpice/pdf/G%20U%20M%20M%20E%20L%20-%20P%20O%20O%20N.pdf)) describes how to calculate the base-spreading resistance from model parameters. I've copied the equation here:

$$
\begin{align}
  r_{\mathrm{bb}'} &= \mathrm{RBM} + 3(\mathrm{RB}-\mathrm{RBM}) \left(\frac{\tan(z) - z}{z\tan^2(z)}\right),\\
  z &= \frac{\sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{12}{\pi}\right)^2 \frac{i_{\mathrm{b}}}{\mathrm{IRB}}} - 1}
           {\frac{24}{\pi^2} \sqrt{\frac{i_{\mathrm{b}}}{\mathrm{IRB}}}},
\end{align}
$$
where \$i_{\mathrm{b}}\$ is base current, RBM is minimum base resistance at high current, RB is zero-bias base resistance, and IRB is current at medium base resistance.

I've applied these equations to several NPNs and compared the results with the measured results from [The Art of Electronics (3rd Ed.)](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Art_of_Electronics.html?id=LAiWPwAACAAJ), and am getting very different results. For instance, [OnSemi provides a spice model for the 2N3904](https://www.onsemi.com/products/discrete-power-modules/general-purpose-and-low-vcesat-transistors/2n3904), where the relevant parameters are: RB=5.8376 IRB=50.3624 RBM=0.634251. Using these values with the above equations (and base current 100uA) yields an rbb of approximately \$5.8\,\mathrm{\Omega}\$. The Art of Electronics in [Table 8.1a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOqta.jpg), however, gives this as \$110\,\mathrm{\Omega}\$.

That IRB looks high.

What accounts for the difference in rbb? Is this a valid method of estimation?

Comment: Matt, Have you pulled up and read, *"The Effects of Distributed Base Potential on Emitter-Current Injection Density and Effective Base Resistance for Stripe Transistor Geometries,"* by Hauser in 1964, yet? That paper does cover your two equations. Gummel & Poon in their 1970 paper used a simplification. But by the time Spice was implemented, Hauser's earlier 1964 paper was included as a complication, providing a better approximation than Gummel & Poon allowed for. I can dig into the equations and development. But I'm less interested in discussing issues with some Spice program or AofE.

Comment: I hadn't, but I just procured a copy and am looking at it now. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: When reading, note that Hauser uses an approach that focuses on dissipation of power to input power, which Spice pretty much doesn't care about. Spice is (and should be) focused on I/V relationships, not power. Getting I/V right helps get power right. But getting power right pretty much does nothing useful in getting the I/V relationship right. Also, Spice cares about having no discontinuities in the first 2 derivatives, plus good behavior at extremes of I and V. That's because such issues are likely during the iterative processes in Spice. Models get massaged to be Spice-friendly.

Comment: I just did a search for you and found a paper that appears to cover much of what I has hinting at, above. In fact... I'm surprised how closely, and impressed at how well he covers what was in mind while searching. He does a better job than I could so now I'm not going to bother writing here, at all. Look up a paper in IEEE Microwave Magazine by Steve Maas called *"Why I Hate Base Resistance,"* 2004. I think you will enjoy it!

Comment: Best wishes, Matt! if you have more question from those papers, let me know. I may be able to find some insight to help out. (No promises. I *am* a hobbyist with perhaps a grand imagination space that carries me far and away at times, but pretty poor training background to bring me back to ground when needed. Never so much as a DC course under my belt. But I'm good at math and I understand it geometrically, as images and movies of transformations in action, not only algebraically, which may lack insight. So I may find something useful for you. But you need to read those papers, first.)

Comment: I will let you know, thank you jonk!

Comment: Again, best wishes, Matt. I like your questioning process! Very detailed. And it is *very good* to possess that kind of detailed curiosity. You will go far, I imagine!! I'd like to help, if I may. But I suspect you will get it entirely on your own! Your kind of curiosity about nailing down details is exactly the right stuff needed to succeed well and to be able to help others succeed in their own endeavours. I love seeing this kind of question.

Comment: If I remember well (I can fail ...), rbb' could be easily related to "null" "harmonic" distortion, by well choosing the quiet point.

Comment: Another tidbit here.  According to [this textbook](https://books.google.com/books/about/Semiconductor_Device_Modeling_with_SPICE.html?id=_QZTAAAAMAAJ), the \$z\$ parameter in your equation is actually formed [via a MacLaurin series approximation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NyYI.jpg).  I doubt it's what is causing such a massive difference, but thought I'd still point it out.

Comment: I re-ran the calculation on another model I found which has `RB=1.733 IRB=1.12054 RBM=0.876202` and got an even lower number.  I believe there is a discrepancy in how this parameter is modeled and how the AoE textbook is getting it via measurement.  I skimmed the chapter and it looks like they are measuring \$e_{n}\$ at a certain \$I_C\$ and then using Equation 8.19 to infer \$r_{bb'}\$.  Therefore the model is attempting to use device physics while the measurement is using noise measurements.  It's possible you might not be able to square the two...

Comment: Thanks @SteKulov. I ran some calculations using equation 8.19 and do indeed get very similar values to the ones listed in the table. AoE's treatment of noise is in agreement with the treatment in Low Noise Electronic Design by Motchenbacher. However, it's less detailed and jumps right to simplifications. Motchenbacher presents a total equivalent input noise voltage, that, when the frequency-dependent terms are omitted, includes a \$2qI_Br_{bb}^2\$ term. Motchenbacher also throws this term out in the simplified "midband noise" expression, but I think that's a mistake. If I perform the (1/2)

Comment: same computation with that term, using min beta, the noise drops down to 88 for the '3904. Of course, bringing the beta up decreases the contribution of that term, but it seems to have a large enough effect to warrant being included.

Comment: Something else worth mentioning: [this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/160987) also measures the 2n3904 and gets 34ohms at 100uA and 30ohms at 1mA (and, according to the base-current dependence of rbb, should only go down at 10mA Ic). I suppose it's possible two different versions of this transistor might have very different actual base resistance values.